# JavaScript return array of keys that are all empty in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I have an array of objects

```
const arrayOfObjects = [{firstKey: '', secondKey: 'someValue', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''},{firstKey: '', secondKey: '', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''}];
```

I need to return an array of keys that are empty in all of the objects in the array. So for the above example, it would return `['firstKey', 'fourthKey']` but not `'secondKey'`, because it is only empty in one of the objects.

I have found a lot of examples (like one below) that return boolean but having trouble finding a way to return the actual empty keys. Thanks

```
const isEmpty = Object.values(object).every(x => (x === ''));
```

Comment: I guess, you just need a filter over here. Rather than making it complicated by using every and then x === ''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the keys from the 1st object in the array, and then filter them by checking for each key that it's empty in all objects with `Array.every()`:

```js
const checkAllEmpty = arr =>
  Object.keys(arr[0] ?? {}) // get the keys from the 1st object or use an empty object as fallback
    .filter(key => arr.every(o => o[key] === '')) // filter the keys by checking each object in the array

const arr = [{firstKey: '', secondKey: 'someValue', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''},{firstKey: '', secondKey: '', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''}]

const result = checkAllEmpty(arr)

console.log(result)
```

Old answer:

Reduce the array to a Map, and count how many times a key is empty. Convert the Map to an an array of `[key, value]` using `Array.from()`, filter all the entries that have a value that is less then the array's length, and map to an array of keys:

```js
const arr = [{firstKey: '', secondKey: 'someValue', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''},{firstKey: '', secondKey: '', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''}]

const result = Array.from(arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    Object.entries(obj)
      .forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v === '') acc.set(k, (acc.get(k) ?? 0) + 1)
      })

    return acc
  }, new Map))
  .filter(([, v]) => v === arr.length)
  .map(([k]) => k)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Marky1298 - I've updated the answer with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) returns `true` when every item satisfies the predicate you pass as a callback. What you actually need is [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{firstKey: '', secondKey: 'someValue', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''},{firstKey: '', secondKey: '', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''}];

const deduplicate = arr => [...new Set(arr)];

const isEmpty = arrayOfObjects.flatMap(x => Object.entries(x)).filter(([, value]) => !value).map(([key]) => key);

const uniqueIsEmpty = deduplicate(isEmpty);

console.log(uniqueIsEmpty);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close, I would just need to make each key unique and only key (not value) in return. Thanks, will work with this

Comment: Yes, thanks

"it would return [firstKey, fourthKey] but not secondKey, because it is only empty in one of the objects"

Answer (score 1):

This version will assume undefined keys are also "empty", in case the objects in your array have inconsistent keys.

```js
const arr = [
    {firstKey: '', secondKey: 'someValue', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''}, 
    {firstKey: '', secondKey: '', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''}
];

const isEmpty = v => v == '';

const result = Array.from(
    arr.reduce((acc, obj) => 
        Object.entries(obj).reduce((_, [k, v]) => 
            acc.set(k, acc.has(k) ? acc.get(k) && isEmpty(v) : isEmpty(v))
        , null)
    , new Map())
).filter(([, v]) => v).map(([k]) => k);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arrayOfObjects = [{firstKey: '', secondKey: 'someValue', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''},{firstKey: '', secondKey: '', thirdkey: 'someValue', fourthKey: ''}];
let k = []
arrayOfObjects.map(obj => { k = k.concat(k, Object.keys(obj))})
let arr = [...new Set(k)];
console.log(arr);
```